# Does Context need to be explicitly set for a ImageButtons when they are created in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

So I'm trying to dynamically create `ImageButton` in an Android app. I'm at a point where I'm creating them in an `array` like so:

```
int size = 10; //you can pretend that this is actually dynamic
ImageButton[] imageButtons = new ImageButton[size]
for(ImageButton imageButton: ImageButtons)
{                imageButton.setId(id);
            imageButton.setCropToPadding(true);
            imageButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageButton.setBackground(null);
            //etc....
}
```

Does the `Context` that is required for the `ImageButton` constructor assume the correct `Context` when they are created like this or do I need explicitly create each ImageButton with the correct `Context` and then add them to an `Array` or `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at all the different view types, they each have a constructor that requires a Context.  So if you are going to create views programmatically, you typically pass the host activity context to the constructor every time.

Comment: I see so using an array and giving it the allocated space wouldn't be sufficient, I would have to pass the context to every ImageButton I create. I wish the ImageButton had a setContext(Context context). That would make it really easy! :D

Comment: You're not doing it in your code sample, but you will have to create a new ImageButton each time through the loop.  Simply allocating the array does not also create each object in the array.